# Raising index on covariant derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, tensors

So suppose $X$ is some vector field and $t$ is a tangent vector to some curve on some smooth manifold. Then $t^a\nabla_a X$ gives the directional derivative of the vector field in the direction of $t$. That makes sense. But what is the geometrical interpretation of raising the index on the derivative operator? For example, $\nabla^a X = g^{ab} \nabla_b X$ where $g$ is a metric tensor, right? But in what way does $\nabla^a X$ differentiate $X$? The expression $\nabla_a X$ is "waiting" for a tangent vector to be inputted so that we can differentiate the vector field $X$ in the direction of that tangent vector. But then it appears that $\nabla^a X$ is "waiting" for a dual vector to be inputted. This is what is confusing me.

EDIT: Would it be correct to say that since $\nabla^a X = g^{ab} \nabla_b X$, then we are just plugging in one dual vector, $\omega$, into $g^{-1}$ and leaving the other slot empty (which gives us a tangent vector), and then we are plugging this tangent vector into $\nabla_b$, so that we are differentiating the vector field $X$ in the direction of $g(\omega, \cdot)$ (which is a tangent vector)?

Comment: As far as I know, in this context you do not really distinguish between covariant and contravariant. [See this great answer to a related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/687882/8157)

Comment: Would it be correct then, to say that since $\nabla^a X = g^{ab} \nabla_b X$, then we are just plugging in one dual vector, $\omega$, into $g$ and leaving the other slot empty (which gives us a tangent vector), and then we are plugging this tangent vector into $\nabla_b$, so that we are differentiating the vector field $X$ in the direction of $g(\omega, \cdot)$ (which is a tangent vector)?

Comment: This could be the answer, but I cannot say for sure, unfortunately. Maybe you should edit your main question, and include this last remark into the main text.